# Raspberry Pi 1 stuck booting Kali after Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service

Tags: kali

I flashed the Kali Linux RaspberryPi w/TFT image from the [official website](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/).

However, booting gets stuck after "Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, instead of using the TFT image, it is possible to flash the Rpi0w Nexmon image for a Pi 1, though it only contains a shell but no desktop.

Using the TFT image without TFT will be a problem because booting will appear stuck or frozen on the HDMI screen, according to a [thread post](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?39027-Freeze-while-booting-on-Pi-1-(B-)&p=77473#post77473):

[@re4son wrote](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?39027-Freeze-while-booting-on-Pi-1-(B-)&p=77473#post77473):

> The one you used does work, but it is configured for a tft display,
>   i.e. when the screen freezes it has switched the output from hdmi to
>   tft, which makes it tricky to use if you don't have a tft ;-)

In a [different thread](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?38669-Kali-will-not-boot-from-SD-card-on-Pi-B&p=76728#post76728), [@re4son wrote](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?38669-Kali-will-not-boot-from-SD-card-on-Pi-B&p=76728#post76728):

> In this case, however, you have to do some minor work yourself to get
>   it running because there is currently no official image for the Pi 1
>   available.
>
> The first image on the site is for a different processor architecture
>   and the second probably works perfectly well on your Pi, except that
>   you can't see what's going on because it displays everything on the
>   non-existing adafruit tft screen that it is configured for
>
> That's not a problem though; you can either:
>
> a) create your own image using the official Kali Linux build scripts,
>   available under:
>   https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-arm-build-scripts,
>   or
>
> b) download the "Raspberry Pi w/TFT" image and manually remove the
>   bits and pieces responsible for directing the output to the tft screen

Compiling an entire image seems like a lot of work.

However, by comparing the "[`rpi-tft.sh`](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-arm-build-scripts/blob/master/rpi-tft.sh)" and "[`rpi.sh`](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-arm-build-scripts/blob/master/rpi.sh)" build scripts, I have figured it out -- how to disable the TFT without compiling a new image.

The first change that you need to reverse starts on [line 236](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-arm-build-scripts/blob/master/rpi-tft.sh#L236):

```
cat << EOF > ${basedir}/bootp/cmdline.txt
```

In "`cmdline.txt`" on the FAT partition, you want to replace the same line from the "[`rpi.sh`](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-arm-build-scripts/blob/master/rpi.sh)" build script, which does not include the "`fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8`".

Next, on the Linux partition, replace the "`/etc/modules`" file with the default "`modules`" file, or just remove the lines added. It is just a header with comments:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

Next, delete the "`/etc/modprobe.d/pitft.conf`" file.

Next, replace the "`/root/.profile`" with the default "`.profile`" file:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n || true
```

Finally, delete the entire "`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`" directory. It should only contain the two files "`10-fbdev.conf`" and "`99-calibration.conf`".

Someone could make a script to automate this.